# how to get form id from ajax and set it in click function in symfony2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

i want to store id in global variable and then store this id  for form edit
here is my xml request:

```
if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $response = new Response();
        $output = array('success' => true, 'title' => $entity->gettitle(), 'id' => $entity->getId(), 'notes' => $entity->getnotes(), 'accountid' => $entity->getaccountid(), 'clientid' => $entity->getClientID(), 'status' => $entity->getstatus(), 'totalamount' => $entity->getTotalAmount(), 'paidamount' => $entity->getPaidAmount(), 'balanceamount' => $entity->getBalanceAmount(), 'createdby' => $entity->getcreatedby(), 'updatedby' => $entity->getupdatedby(), 'createddatetime' => $entity->getcreateddatetime(), 'updateddatetime' => $entity->getupdateddatetime());
         $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
         $response->setContent(json_encode($output));
         return $response;
    }
```

and here is my ajax code:

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {              
         e.preventDefault();
         var url = $(this).attr('action');
         var data = $(this).serialize();
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: data,
         }).done(function( result ) {
                 invoiceid=result.id;
            if(result.success) {
                $('#result').css({'color':'black','background-color':'#8F8','display':'Block','width':'200px'});
                $('#result').html('Invoices Record Inserted');
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('#result').hide();
                    },3000);
            }
         });
         this.reset();
     });
     $("#edit").click(function(){

    window.location.href= "{{ path('invoices_edit', {'id': invoiceid }) }}";  
            });
```

and here is myjson response who contain id:

```
 {"success":true,"title":"invoice","id":57,"notes":"gjgjgjgjg","accountid":1,"clientid":"5","status":"sent","totalamount":"90000","paidamount":"45000","balanceamount":"45000","createdby":1,"updatedby":1,"createddatetime":{"date":"2013-10-03 17:37:00","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Asia\/Karachi"},"updateddatetime":{"date":"2013-10-03 17:37:00","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Asia\/Karachi"}}
```

when i alert invoiceid then it show value of result.id but invoiceid not pass to click function,how i do this?

Comment: anybody who have solution above question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.done()` is callback.

You need to pass result.id or call $('#edit').click() in done callback

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var invoiceId;
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("form").submit(function(e) {              
         e.preventDefault();
         var url = $(this).attr('action');
         var data = $(this).serialize();
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: data,
           })
           .success(function( result ) {
              invoiceid=result.id;
             //after setting you can call click like this
              $('#edit').click(); // or use trigger()
               if(result.success) {
                $('#result').css({'color':'black',
                      'background-color':'#8F8','display':'Block','width':'200px'});
                $('#result').html('Invoices Record Inserted');
                setTimeout(function(){$('#result').hide();},3000);
              }
            });
         this.reset();
     });

   $("#edit").click(function(){
      = "{{ path('invoices_edit', {'id': invoiceid }) }}";
   });

 });

</script>
```

Comment: my formid is 55 but when i click #edit it moves the form whose id is 54

Comment: @user2833510, Is invoice id is your form id? are you referring a data from server or `Html form`?

Comment: when i used your code then i get error like this Variable "invoiceid" does not exist in InvoicesInvoicesBundle:Invoices:new.html.twig at line 342

Comment: @user2833510, your code only defines `invoiceid`. Check it. I have not added any other than calling $('#edit).click(). So please specify `var invoiceid` in a global scope

Comment: i initilzed var invoiceid like this <script type="text/javascript">
  var invoiceid; but same error

Comment: @user2833510, please make sure you have initialized above the ajax call and a click function.

Comment: i initilized above the ajax call and click function

Comment: @user2833510, please add your json response you are getting as well the rendered html contains the `<script>` has a invoiceid variable in your question

Comment: i attached my json response plz check

Comment: @user2833510, I have made some changes in code. see that. i used `success` now. just give a try

Comment: Again same problem exist